# Bootstrap4 align-items-end not working

Tags: html, css, row, vertical-alignment, bootstrap-4

So I've been working on this for the better half of 2 weeks now and can not seem to get this to work out as intended. I'm starting to think that it might be an issue with how deep the rows/columns in question are, but would really like to get some outside insight.

In short, it is the page with -> 2 rows in which the second row contains -> 2 columns in which the second contains -> 3 rows being a breadcrumb, the main content of each page and a footer. Should the page need to extend the nav should remain static. I vaguely recall when starting out seeing some posts of people trying to do a similar layout, but have not been able to find those posts again.

Below is the code in question in as stripped down a form as I could get it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap and self-made CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">       

        <!-- various imports -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chivo:900" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
        html, body{
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
        h2 {
            font-family: 'Chivo', sans-serif;
        }
        </style>
    </head> 
    <body  style="background-color:  #000;"> <!-- bgc: black -->
    <div class="container-fluid h-100">
        <div class="row h-25"style="background-color:  #F00;"> <!-- bgc: red -->
            <div class="col">
                <h1>In the header!</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row h-75" style="background-color:  #0F0;"> <!-- bgc: green -->
            <div class="col-sm-2 no-gutters h-100" style="background-color:  #00F;"> <!-- bgc: blue -->
                <nav>
                    <h2>In the nav bar!</h2>
                </nav>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-10 no-gutters h-100" style="background-color:  #FF0;"> <!-- bgc: yellow --> 
                <div class="row align-items-start" style="background-color:  #FFF;"> <!-- bgc: white -->
                    <div class="col">
                        <main>
                            <h2>In the breadcrumb!</h2>
                        </main>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row align-items-center" style="background-color:  #0FF;"> <!-- bgc: cyan -->
                    <div class="col">
                        <main>
                            <h2>In the main!</h2>
                        </main>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row align-items-end" style="background-color:  #F0F;"> <!-- bgc: magenta -->
                    <div class="col">
                        <footer>
                            <h2>In the footer</h2>
                        </footer>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My questions are:
1. Can a layout like this even be done in bootstrap4?
2. If it can, what changes are needed to make it work?
3. The "nav column" when collapsing on smaller screens remains at h-100 instead of shrinking, am I using the subclasses correctly for the fluid scaling?

Comment: It can be done, however if you are using bootstrap4, recommend using flexbox instead of containers and rows. https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't have much experience using rows and containers in bootstrap 4, however I can provide you flexbox implementation of such a layout. If you understand flexbox, you can use the below code as reference to create your own layout.

Following is a barebone flexbox code to achieve the layout hierarchy you have mentioned. I realize it's not the best of answers, but hope it helps.

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column" style="height: 100%"> <!-- Main container declared as flexbox column -->

    <div class="h-25"> <!-- Row 1 in the container -->
    </div>

    <div class="h-75 d-flex row"> <!-- Row 2 in the container. This itself is a flexbox row -->

        <div class="col-sm-2"> <!-- Column 1 of the row -->
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-10 d-flex flex-column"> <!-- Column 2 of the row -->

            <div> <!-- Row 1 of the column -->
            </div>

            <div> <!-- Row 2 of the column -->
            </div>

            <div> <!-- Row 3 of the column -->
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Refer to boostrap4 flexbox document to understand flexbox https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/:

**EDIT**

Here's a working plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/WWT5XoHyvLf2paKQItSH?p=preview